# std::transform with an overloaded conversion function

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++17

I want to transform all objects - which are of type, say, `char` - from one container `c` and store the results - which are of type `foo` - in a different container `v`. The desired conversion function is an overloaded function - call it `to_foo`.

Consider the following [example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8243ed73b53d3be2):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>    

struct foo {};

foo to_foo(char) { return {}; }
foo to_foo(int) { return {}; }

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 1> c;
    std::vector<foo> v(c.size());

//  cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "to_foo" is intended:
    std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), v.begin(), to_foo);

//  ok:
    std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), v.begin(), [](auto const& ch) { return to_foo(ch); });
}
```

While it's somehow plausible to me that in the first transform the compiler doesn't know which overload of `to_foo` it should take (on the other, couldn't he deduce it from the `value_type` of the iterators?), I don't understand why he is able to do so in the second transform. What's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell it which overload to use by casting `to_foo`:

```cpp
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), v.begin(), static_cast<foo (*)(char)>(to_foo));
```

The type of the unary operation parameter of `std::transform` is a different template argument than the one used for the iterators. So it has to use the type of the value you pass to deduce the template argument. `to_foo`'s type is ambiguous, so it can't complete that process. Casting the function pointer to a specific overload type makes it unambiguous.

---

In the second form, the lambda is a callable object, and the use of `auto` makes the object's `()` operator a function template:

```cpp
struct NamelessGenericLambda {
    template <typename T>
    foo operator ()(T const& ch) { return to_foo(ch); }
};
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), v.begin(), NamelessGenericLambda{});
```

The type is clear so it can instantiate the `std::transform` template.

Then somewhere inside `std::transform` it will try to instantiate the `operator ()` template by passing a `char`. Because it passes an unambiguous type, the compiler deduces `ch` is a char. Then it picks the right overload of `to_foo` using regular overload resolution.